# What is the significance of "error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol:" when loading libglib in debug mode?

Tags: linux, ld, glib

The following command succeeds without errors: `python3 -c 'from gi.repository import GLib'`.

However, when debugging some glib-related segmentation faults, I ran the same command with `LD_DEBUG=files` (on multiple versions of Debian and Ubuntu) and get a bunch of errors related to libglib and libgobject.

These are unmodified libraries directly from the repositories (see "Environment" below for details).

**Question:** What is the significance of these errors? Can they be safely ignored, and if so, why? OR can they contribute to errors later on in the program, and if so, is there a workaround to fix this, or are the packages simply broken and must be fixed by modifying the source?

**An example of the errors:**

```
 16306: opening file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0]; direct_opencount=1
 16306:
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_check_init (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_unload (fatal)
```

**Environment**

- tested on 5 different computers with 4 different distros: Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.10, Debian 8.4, and someone's custom distro
- Relevant package versions (for 15.10 Ubuntu distro only):

  - python3    3.4.3-4ubuntu1 (also: python3-all python3-all-dev python3-dbg python3-dev)
  - python3-gi    3.16.2-1build1 (also: python3-gi-cairo python3-gi-dbg)
  - gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64    1.44.0-1
  - libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64    1.44.0-1
  - libglib2.0-0:amd64    2.46.2-1ubuntu2

**Full command output:**

```
$ LD_DEBUG=files python3 -c 'from gi.repository import GLib'
 16306: 
 16306: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libpthread.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74ce030d50  base: 0x00007f74cde19000   size: 0x000000000021c490
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cde1ff10  phdr: 0x00007f74cde19040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libdl.so.2 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cde17d88  base: 0x00007f74cdc15000   size: 0x0000000000203110
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cdc15ed0  phdr: 0x00007f74cdc15040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libutil.so.1 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libutil.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cdc13dc0  base: 0x00007f74cda12000   size: 0x0000000000202118
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cda12f10  phdr: 0x00007f74cda12040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=librt.so.1 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=librt.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cda10d70  base: 0x00007f74cd80a000   size: 0x0000000000207c18
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cd80c350  phdr: 0x00007f74cd80a040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libexpat.so.1 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libexpat.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cd808dc0  base: 0x00007f74cd5e1000   size: 0x0000000000228088
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cd5e4b90  phdr: 0x00007f74cd5e1040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libz.so.1 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libz.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cd5dfdd0  base: 0x00007f74cd3c6000   size: 0x000000000021a228
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cd3c8220  phdr: 0x00007f74cd3c6040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libm.so.6 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libm.so.6 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cd3c4da8  base: 0x00007f74cd0c5000   size: 0x0000000000300158
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cd0ca580  phdr: 0x00007f74cd0c5040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by python3 [0]
 16306: file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cd0beba0  base: 0x00007f74ccd1a000   size: 0x00000000003aaa20
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74ccd3bc50  phdr: 0x00007f74ccd1a040  phnum:                 10
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: initialize program: python3
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: transferring control: python3
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0];  dynamically loaded by python3 [0]
 16306: file=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74ccb1f9e8  base: 0x00007f74cc8da000   size: 0x000000000024e648
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cc8ea4f0  phdr: 0x00007f74cc8da040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libgthread-2.0.so.0 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: file=libgthread-2.0.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cc8d8de8  base: 0x00007f74cc6d8000   size: 0x0000000000201048
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cc6d86d0  phdr: 0x00007f74cc6d8040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libgirepository-1.0.so.1 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: file=libgirepository-1.0.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cc6d6ce0  base: 0x00007f74cc4a5000   size: 0x0000000000232688
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cc4ac380  phdr: 0x00007f74cc4a5040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libgobject-2.0.so.0 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: file=libgobject-2.0.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cc4a3b80  base: 0x00007f74cc252000   size: 0x0000000000252fc8
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cc25d330  phdr: 0x00007f74cc252040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libglib-2.0.so.0 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: file=libglib-2.0.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cc24fd40  base: 0x00007f74cbf43000   size: 0x000000000030e6a8
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cbf5d580  phdr: 0x00007f74cbf43040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libffi.so.6 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: file=libffi.so.6 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cbf41de8  base: 0x00007f74cbd3b000   size: 0x0000000000207668
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cbd3c870  phdr: 0x00007f74cbd3b040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libgmodule-2.0.so.0 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1 [0]
 16306: file=libgmodule-2.0.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cbd39de8  base: 0x00007f74cbb37000   size: 0x00000000002031b8
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cbb381b0  phdr: 0x00007f74cbb37040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libgio-2.0.so.0 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1 [0]
 16306: file=libgio-2.0.so.0 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cbb32c68  base: 0x00007f74cb7bd000   size: 0x0000000000379ac8
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cb7f0c50  phdr: 0x00007f74cb7bd040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libpcre.so.3 [0];  needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: file=libpcre.so.3 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cb7bbc90  base: 0x00007f74cb54f000   size: 0x000000000026d168
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cb550710  phdr: 0x00007f74cb54f040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libselinux.so.1 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: file=libselinux.so.1 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cb54bd68  base: 0x00007f74cb32a000   size: 0x00000000002248f0
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cb330310  phdr: 0x00007f74cb32a040  phnum:                  8
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=libresolv.so.2 [0];  needed by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: file=libresolv.so.2 [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74cb326d88  base: 0x00007f74cb113000   size: 0x0000000000216a68
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cb116a90  phdr: 0x00007f74cb113040  phnum:                  9
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 16306: 
 16306: opening file=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]; direct_opencount=1
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: file=/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0];  dynamically loaded by python3 [0]
 16306: file=/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0];  generating link map
 16306:   dynamic: 0x00007f74caff0df8  base: 0x00007f74cadf0000   size: 0x00000000002011f0
 16306:     entry: 0x00007f74cadf0990  phdr: 0x00007f74cadf0040  phnum:                  7
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling init: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
 16306: 
 16306: opening file=/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]; direct_opencount=1
 16306: 
 16306: opening file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0]; direct_opencount=1
 16306: 
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_check_init (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_unload (fatal)
 16306: opening file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 [0]; direct_opencount=1
 16306: 
 16306: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_check_init (fatal)
 16306: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_module_unload (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_io_condition_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_loop_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_loop_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_loop_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_loop_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_context_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_context_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_context_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_main_context_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_source_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_io_channel_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_io_channel_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_io_channel_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_io_channel_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_pollfd_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_pollfd_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_pollfd_get_type (fatal)
 16306: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: g_pollfd_get_type (fatal)
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: python3 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgirepository-1.0.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so [0]
 16306: 
 16306: 
 16306: calling fini: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0]
 16306:
```

Comment: It's obviously the symbol you used does not exist . This could result from linking a different library from the headers you've adapted.

Comment: @GeminiKeith I am using unmodified libraries directly from the Debian/ Ubuntu repositories. I do not know much about the structure of these libraries.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Clarified this in my question.

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with C. Please remove that tag.

Comment: Your question is about a tool used to link **machine code** translated from C among dozens of other languages, dare I say assembly and yet you've added the C tag, but none of the others... why not add the c++ tag too? Why not add the Haskell tag? Because uhh, the question is about a tool and not a language... hmmm?

Comment: @Seb OK, thanks, I removed C tag. I tagged it C because GLib is written in C, and the problem might be in GLib, but I guess that's not enough of a reason. Is there another tag I should add instead?

Comment: It's a linker problem, not a language problem; I think you have sufficient tags now. Is it possible that you might be suffering a corrupt installation?

Comment: I tested it on four different computers with 4 different distros (Debian, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.05, and a custom distro). It's unlikely that they are all corrupted. @Seb

Comment: Oops, I meant 15.10. Added distro and  package versions to Environment section.

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing the same thing with a python app that uses GLib and GStreamer.  I ran it with LD_FILES=true and piped the output:

```
$ ./testlib.sh lib/hls.py 2>&1 | grep fatal |awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' | sort -u
__driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
g_io_channel_get_type
g_io_condition_get_type
g_main_context_get_type
g_main_loop_get_type
g_module_check_init
g_module_unload
g_pollfd_get_type
g_source_get_type
```

__driDriverGetExtensions_swrast() seems to be a little special, but all the others can be found on the [Gnome Developer Boxed Types](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Boxed-Types.html) page or in [Dyanmic Loading of Modules](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Dynamic-Loading-of-Modules.html).

I'm still not sure whether this is the reason my app segfaults every time I run it now.  The section for GModuleCheckInit() says:

> If a module contains a function named g_module_check_init() it is
>   called automatically when the module is loaded.

So it's possible that it is normal for g_module_check_init() not to be found and the related error message is harmless.  I wonder if that's the reason that module loading continues, instead of immediately exiting with some error code.

For I while, I was building and installing all the GStreamer libs and command-line tools myself to get the latest stable version (GStreamer 1.10.4).  But when it started segfaulting, I wiped every gstreamer lib I could find under /usr and installed the version that comes with my Ubuntu distro, GStreamer 1.2.  It's still seg-faulting, so maybe something is still missing.

I know this is only a partial answer, but it's too long for a comment.  Maybe someone can add something.